# Shortest method for string to boolean conversion in this scenario

Tags: string, c#-4.0, int, boolean, .net-4.5

I have 4 possible [string] values for an input parameter - "0", "1", "false", "true".

These possible values need to be converted to boolean. With "0" mapping to false and "1" mapping to true and the strings "false" and "true" to respective booleans.

What would be the shortest and optimal way to do this?

Comment: Voting -1 as this question for "shortest and optimal" may have only opinion based answers, you don't provide any measurable scenario and it falls into the http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask category

Answer (score 1):

You could include `str == "1"`:

```
foreach(string str in new[]{ "0", "1", "false", "true"})
{
    bool isTrue;
    isTrue = Boolean.TryParse(str, out isTrue) || str == "1";
    Console.WriteLine(isTrue);
}
```

For what it's worth, an extension method:

```
public static bool ParseBool(this string input, bool oneIsTrue = true)
{
    bool b;
    return (oneIsTrue && input == "1") || bool.TryParse(input, out b);
}

// ...
foreach(string str in new[]{ "0", "1", "false", "true", "True", "TRUE"})
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.ParseBool());
}
```

Comment: That's entirely different than the foreach from your original answer ;) But what's with the `out b` reference?

Comment: @Moriarty: The extension is equivalent to the `foreach`, isn't it? I've added the extension just because OP was asking for the shortest code. There isnn't anything shorter than `str.ParseBool()`. The `out` is necessary to use `bool.TryParse`. It's an `out` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do:

```
//string value is stored in str
boolean bool = (str.equals("0")||str.equals("false"))?false:true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple one.

```
string[] ar = { "0", "1", "true", "false" };
var boolArray = ar.Select(x => (x=="1"||x=="true")?true:false).ToArray();
```